# Coconut cream from coconut butter

Tags: butter, cream, coconut, cocktails

How can I make coconut cream from coconut butter? I am making Pina Colada cocktail and I need coconut cream. I have one original coconut cream (for the sake of not advertising, I will not put here name of this brand), from the original Pina Colada, and yes, it tastes good, but, I would like to make my own. So I bought biological coconut oil (which solidifies so it turns into butter almost instantly in the refrigerator), and I tried to mix it with some low fat coconut mil, some water, but nothing worked. I mix it well and put it a little bit on the low fire, but as soon as I put it in fridge, it soon solidifies, so I cannot really use it to put it in the cocktail, since it becomes gritty, so the cocktail is not good. Any advice, guys? Newb here on this stack, so thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

Coconut cream is a more concentrated version of coconut milk, with more fat but also more coconut solids. Coconut milk won't mix well with additional coconut oil, because without the additional solids the emulsion will be unstable.

If you'd like to make your own coconut cream from scratch, you'll need a coconut. Alternatively, buy it directly, or skim it off rested coconut milk.

Answer (score 4):

Coconut oil and coconut cream, though both are made from the flesh of coconuts, are quite different things, and it's difficult to substitute one for the other here. That said, you mentioned that you had coconut milk when you were describing your attempt at making your own coconut cream, and the good news here is that coconut milk is not that far off from coconut cream itself; it's mostly a matter of water content. You can likely use your coconut milk as is for your pina coladas; they won't be as rich as if you had the proper coconut cream, but you may be able to tweak your ratios of ingredients to compensate somewhat.

On another note, [another popular pina colada recipe](https://mixthatdrink.com/pina-colada/) calls for a mixture of regular heavy cream and 'cream of coconut' rather than 'coconut cream' - cream of coconut is a sweetened product that you might not be able to find where you are, but it's [not hard to make your own](https://www.artofdrink.com/ingredient/cream-of-coconut-recipe), and the recipe even calls for coconut milk, rather than coconut cream.

Comment: I make my own all the time and it's actually very easy, and far cheaper than coco lopez. Tastes fresher too. The trick is to find thick coconut milk, don't go for the light stuff, get a Caribbean or Thai brand if you can. Sometimes I get lazy and open up a can of pure coconut cream, then add a spoon of it plus a shot of agave nectar in. Works really well.

Comment: Now I want a pina colada at 9:55 in the morning. Life isn't fair...

Comment: @GdD quarantine time is like airport time.  It's never too early for a drink.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to try.

Coconut butter = Creamed coconut = 100% pureed coconut meat. (ie puree a fresh coconut or buy a jar just ensuring the only ingredient in it is coconut.)

For 200ml coconut milk use 40g creamed coconut (=coconut butter) with 170ml of warm to room temperature water and blitz it till you have milk.

As coconut cream is just richer.  I tried 120g of creamed coconut to 100ml of warm water and it seems pretty good to me, though can't guarantee this is exactly 200ml.

NB "Cream of coconut" tends to be sweetened and so is different again - or at least read label.  Coconut cream should just contain coconut and water.
NB Solidified coconut oil is not coconut butter - just solid oil.

Unfortunately naming doesn't seem to be very consistent for any of these products.
Hope this helps a bit.